# Jquery stop submit and get data from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I'm trying to use jquery to get data from a form and stop the form submiting using this code:

```
$form = $('form#signup')
$form.submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var $input=$('#signup :input')
  console.log($input.username)
  alert($input.username)
})
```

but the form still `post`s the data and the alert box does not appear.Also firebug brings up the error `$ is not defined` and Node.js crashes

the form (writen in jade):

```
html
  head
    script(src='javascripts/signupValidation.js')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='javascripts/validator.js')
  body
    form(id='signup',method='post',action='/signup')
      label Firstname
      input(type='text', name='firstname')
      label Lastname
      input(type='text', name='lastname')
      label Username
      input(type='text', name='username')
      label Password
      input(type='password', name='password')
      label Password again
      input(type='password', name='password2')
      label Email
      input(type='email', name='email')

  input(type='submit',value='Sign up', onclick="")
```

Comment: NITPICK: Use semicolons! It is bad practice to not use them and if you ever want to compress your code, you will need them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code [not issue with form submission]

`$input.username` is not valid jQuery to reference another element.

```
var usernameInput = $input.filter('[name="username"]');
```

Looks like you are not adding the code on document.ready so you probably are attaching it to nothing. Change it to be:

```
jQuery( function() {
    $form = $('form#signup');
    $form.submit(function(event){
    });
}
```

Also looks like you are including the validation code before the jQuery code. I bet looking at the JavaScript console in the browser has some nice error messages.

Comment: running my code when jquery was ready fixed the submit problem, I'm still getting used to the idea of asynchronous coding

Answer (score 3):

If your form-related JS is in the file `signupValidation.js`, you need to move the script call that includes that file to be *after* the jquery include.

I'd probably clean up the form code a tiny bit, too:

```
$('form#signup').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var $input = $(this).find('[name=username]');
  console.log($input.val());
  alert($input.val());
})
```

You might be interested in looking at [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the form from submiting with `return false` :

```
$form.submit(function(event){

  var $input=$('#signup :input');
  console.log($input.username);
  alert($input.username);

 // data = array of all the information collected from the input tags
 //data = $form.serizalize(); will also work
 data = $(this).serialize();    


  return false;
});
```

`data` would be an array with the information you need, i recommend `console.log(data)` so you can see all of it's structure and then you can use it as you wish for example:

```
if(data.something == anything){
    doThis();
}
```

And i highly recommend adding an `;` at the end of your javascript sentences

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: yes, but sometimes there is something more happening, `return false` will also work as `event.preventPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); ` and another function i cant remember now, so it's safer to do it this way

Comment: @gilbertbw Added how to get the data from the form, check it out

Comment: how do I use the data variable?

Answer (score 0):

Like other people I've had luck with code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Prevent form submission
    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

To prevent form submission. But also, these days it's pretty common that there are scripts on the page which go behind your back and add little candy-coated features like animations and "shake-off" effects to HTML forms. It's possible for those script to get in the way in situations like this, because they might have their own javascript-fu for submissions.